# ¿Solucionar error "NetworkError: There was an error in the connection because HTTP 409" en Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

Hemos desarrollado varios proyectos con Google Apps Script y los clientes nos están reportando varios casos de

> NetworkError: There was an error in the connection because HTTP 409" en Google Apps Script

¿A qué se debe este error?

Comment: Bienvenido. En mi opinión la ayuda que estás buscando se puede solicitar aquí pero no de la forma que la has redactado pues así como está parece lo que llamamos una pregunta "principalmente basada en opiniones", es decir, que cualquier respuesta sería válida.

Comment: Hay varas preguntas sobre este error en Google Apps Script en stackoverflow en inglés, así que sí, a otros les ha pasado. Una de hace una hora (aún sin respuesta) [¿Why i get error 409 when execute apps script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58598322/1595451)

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58598322/1595451

Comment: Hola @Rubén, gracias por tu respuesta estare pendiente del post que me compartes.

Comment: Se ha reportado como arreglado. Por favor confirma que así ha sido en tu caso.

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a [#16](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143438990#comment16) el problema ha sido resuelto y no se debería presentar de nuevo.

---

Aparentemente se trata de un error que en estos días les está ocurriendo a algunos usuarios de Google Apps Script. En el "Issue Tracker" existe un reporte que fue creado hace un par de años el cual fue marcado como "Fixed" hace unos días, pero aún así hay comentarios de que que el problema se seguía presentando. Para facilitar el seguimiento se creó un nuevo issue en el que hoy alguien comentó que estaba resuelto pero alguien más que aún se seguía presentando el problema.

Te sugiero "estrellar" el nuevo issue para seguirlo e indicar a Google que te interesa el tema. Esto es conveniente porque ayuda en que Google le de mayor prioridad para revisar lo que esté pasando.

Nuevo issue [409 status code responses from appscript (google sheets add-on)](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143438990)

Anterior [Repeat http 409 errors in add-ons](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62013415)